# SOAP error : Axis 2 AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, web-services, soap-client

I have problem with my webservice client which build using Axis 1.3.1 I
encounter below error when executing the webservice:

```
[9/5/14 15:05:47:211 EDT] 0000018f ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service Uncaught service() exception thrown by servlet SWPChooseAccountServlet: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org/apache/axis2/databinding/ADBBean.serialize(Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter;)V
    at org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBDataSource.serialize(ADBDataSource.java:90)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMSourcedElementImpl.java:781)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.internalSerialize(OMElementImpl.java:967)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.serializeInternally(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:283)
    at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPEnvelopeImpl.internalSerialize(SOAPEnvelopeImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSerializableImpl.serializeAndConsume(OMSerializableImpl.java:207)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:74)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
```

The webservice client is deployed in IBM WAS 8.5.5.1 My temporary solution is
to add axis2-adb-1.4.1.jar to WebSphere app server shared library and add
the library as a reference library in the Java class loader (Classes loaded
with local class loader first (parent last))

Comment: Can you post the Servlet code here?

Comment: I fixed this problem with Axis1.4 version of jars when i used isolated shared library.Bt without shared library when i used Axis 1.4 verson jar inside the lib folder ..it giving me same mentioned error...I dnt why it is working with shared library but not working with lib...any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks
It works.

Adding Shared Libraries For axix2 in WAS 8.5

- Login into WAS admin console.
- Go to the Environment Link
- Click on Shared libraries
- Click on new; Select the scope of this variable.
- Provide the name and class path value as per the library location of jars.

  Press apply and then save button.
- Now click on Servers > webSphere Appliacatio servers.
- With in the list of servers select your server.
- Click on Java and Process Management > Class Loader
- Go new and select “Class loader order” and choose “Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)”.
- Apply and save.
- Now Click on Shared library references  under “Additional Properties” section and include your added shared library variable name.
- Now restart server instance to see the effect of whole task.